# Ruby on Rails: How do I specify which method a form_tag points to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this:

```
<% form_tag :controller => :proposals, :method => :bulk_action do %>
```

but it errors in the create method... which is weird because I'm trying to tell stuff to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:method` parameter specifies the [HTTP request method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Request_methods).  You're probably looking for `:action` instead:

```
<% form_tag :controller => :proposals, :action => :bulk_action do %>
```

This will create a form that points to `bulk_action` in `ProposalsController`.

Comment: lol... i had this before... the reason it wasn't working was because I had = instead of == when i checked for different commits